# Cannot use object of type as array

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

I'm trying to render my order in my page validation but when refresh my validation.html.twig i got this error:

> Error: Cannot use object of type FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Address as
>   array
>
> if (!isset($order['tva']['%'.$entity->getTva()->getValue()]))

but i don't see anything wrong in my controller:

bill

```
public function bill()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $generator = $this->container->get('security.secure_random');
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $address = $session->get('address');
    $cart = $session->get('cart');
    $order = array();
    $totalHT = 0;
    $totalTTC = 0;

    $order = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Address')->find($address['address']);
    $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('cart')));

    foreach($entities as $entity)
    {
        $priceHT = ($entity->getPrice() * $cart[$entity->getId()]);
        $priceTTC = ($entity->getPrice() * $cart[$entity->getId()] / $entity->getTva()->getMultiplicate());
        $totalHT += $priceHT;
        $totalTTC += $priceTTC;

        if (!isset($order['tva']['%'.$entity->getTva()->getValue()]))
            $order['tva']['%'.$entity->getTva()->getValue()] = round($priceTTC - $priceHT,2);
        else
            $order['tva']['%'.$entity->getTva()->getValue()] += round($priceTTC - $priceHT,2);

        $order['entity'][$order->getId()] = array('reference' => $order->getName(),
                                                 'quantity' => $cart[$entity->getId()],
                                                 'priceHT' => round($entity->getPrice(),2),
                                                 'priceTTC' => round($entity->getPrice() / $entity->getTva()->getMultiplicate(),2));
    }

    $order['address'] = array('surname' => $address->getSurname(),
        'name' => $address->getName(),
        'phone' => $address->getPhone(),
        'address' => $address->getAddress(),
        'zipcode' => $address->getZipcode(),
        'city' => $address->getCity(),
        'country' => $address->getCountry(),
        'complement' => $address->getComplement());

    $order['priceHT'] = round($totalHT,2);
    $order['priceTTC'] = round($totalTTC,2);
    $order['token'] = bin2hex($generator->nextBytes(20));

    return $order;
}
```

ValidationAction

```
public function validationAction()
{
    if ($this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST')
        $this->setAddressOnSession();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $prepareOrder = $this->forward('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:prepareOrder');
    $order = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Address')->find($prepareOrder->getContent() );
    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:validation.html.twig', array('order' => $order));
}
```

Comment: I think that `$order` is an object. Property of an object can't be accessed like an array, for example `$order['tva']`. Unless the object implements `ArrayAccess`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning Address object to the $order variable by `$order = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Address')->find($address['address']);` and then you want to use it as an array here `$order['tva'].....` and further down in your code. You have to work with $order by its methods/properties like `$order->getTVA()`.